# How can I run a build from Team city that uses code from a different pinned build?

Tags: .net, deployment, build-automation, teamcity-7.0

I have 3 different TeamCity build configurations.

1. Continuous Integration
2. QA
3. Training
4. Production ( Doesn't exist yet )

When my QA build runs, its versions my assemblies with the x.x.{build}.{revision} numbers from Subversion. What I would like to do is to be able to pin a build that QA deems to be acceptable, and to have the Training, and Production builds effectively pull the most recent pinned build revision, and rebuild, unit test, and deploy **using the same build numbers as the QA build**.

The unit test and deployment are really outside of the scope here, and I have them handled, its the version numbers that have me stuck right now. I don't know a ton about what TeamCity does when a build is pinned either, do I even need to worry about pulling a revision or is it kept on hand by TC?

Is this something that TeamCity can do?  Is there documentation somewhere that I didn't see?

I am by no means a deployment engineer, but for now, I have been elected, so I need to make it happen.

Some specifics:
I am using TeamCity 7.1.1
VS2012
.NET 4.5

Comment: is it really a good idea to use the same build numbers as the QA? after all, i'm assuming you're rebuilding because there is some different compilation constants which implies the builds *are different* - thus the build numbers should be different. why do you want/need them the same? (as this could be very confusing down the track) - perhaps share the same SVN revision id and have a different TC build number

Answer (score 0):

Pinning in TC is used to make sure that the build is not cleaned up, there are no dependencies on the pinning action, so you cannot perform a separate action when a build is pinned.

Instead you could add another build, that you can only start manually, and will perform the necessary tasks.
Regarding the build number, a better way would be to use the generated build number from the manually started build.

Another way to go would be to perform all your tasks on your continuous build. This is called [Continuous Deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Automate_deployment).